# Pandas extract index of row and use the extracted index to collect data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a unique situation and I'm not sure how to phrase it to get an answer to a question similar to mine in Google. I have a Pandas dataframe and each row number in these dataframes corresponds to a file name I need data from. For example,  `row 1` corresponds to a file `1.txt`,  `row 2` corresponds to a file `2.txt`. I need to be able to use the row number to navigate to these text files under `some/path/1.txt` and use `linecache` to get the second line of the file and append that to a under a column in my dataframe. The end result would be something like this:

```
Some_data   Important_column
stuff       data_extracted_from_line_2_of_some/path/1.txt
more_stuff  data_extracted_from_line_2_of_some/path/2.txt
more_stuff  data_extracted_from_line_2_of_some/path/3.txt
```

I'm having a feeling this will `lambda` keyword, but I'm not sure what to do since the data lies in files outside the dataframe.

Comment: share sample rows of ur data, with expected output

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `index` and use its values to construct the string passed to `linecache`, how about?

```
import linecache
import os
import pandas as pd

print('Files in file path:\n')
files = os.listdir('path_to_files')
print(files,'\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1,len(files)+1), columns=['Important_column'])
df['Important_column'] = [linecache.getline(os.path.join('path_to_files', str(i) + '.txt'),2) for i in df.index]

print("Df:\n")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Files in file path:

['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt'] 

Df:

  Important_column
1    I am file 1\n
2    I am file 2\n
3    I am file 3\n
```

Might need additional editing to remove a `\n`